# WebRTC vs SIP for P2P Voip

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, sip

I am going to provide a voip system for p2p calling (both video and Audio).
Main devices in the system are Android an iOS mobile phone.
We don't fill it required but we think it is a good option to have support for Browser based users to use this system.
I know sip and webRTC have specific features which makes it hard to choose one and say it is better. But I need some clarification to help me understand for a limited usage of P2P video/Audio calling system which technology is a better option and why?